# Derby how to add NOT NULL constraint on an existing column

Tags: java, sql, derby, ddl

I have been searching for solutions to this, all what I have seen doesn't work, currently I am trying: `ALTER TABLE INVOICE_RECORDS ALTER COLUMN SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL` but it doesn't work.

Error message is: `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "VARCHAR" at line 1, column 53.`

I am running this in a JavaFX app.

I just want to add the NOT NULL constraint to the SERIAL_NUMBER column.

Comment: If you just want to add the `NOT NULL`, just take out the `VARCHAR(10)` from your statement; the rest is fine. Here's the documentation: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.15/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html#rrefsqlj81859__rrefsqlj37860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Bryan Pendleton's comment I tried

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICE_RECORDS ALTER COLUMN SERIAL_NUMBER NOT NULL
```

...and it worked for me. Removing `VARCHAR(10)` did the trick.

Thanks Bryan!

Answer (score 1):

[TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-alter-command.htm) says to do it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICE_RECORDS MODIFY SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work, `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "MODIFY" at line 1, column 27.`

Comment: I don't know for which DBMS that tutorial is supposed to be, but it's wrong for several DBMS including Postgres, Oracle, DB2, Firebird and Apache Derby

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ALTER TABLE INVOICE_RECORDS ADD CONSTRAINT INVOICE_SERIAL_NUM NOT NULL(SERIAL_NUMBER);
```